# How can i enable Credit payment option in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

How can i manage returned-amount to customer's store credit so they can purchase another product by using that amount?

Comment: Store Credit is not built into Magento 1.9, you'll need to find an extension that will provide you with your solution, or develop one yourself.

Comment: Did you find any free stuff?